# Include data files in a Silverlight app

Tags: silverlight

I have some XML files marked as "Content" that should be copied into the application's XAP file. How can I read these files from within Silverlight?

I know how to read files normally in .NET. So what I'm looking for is a way to find where Windows stuck the files and any realavent security issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly how to read files from within the xap but if you just want to be able to load the files at runtime then this will work.

You can set the files to be embedded resources. You then get access to them using the following:

```
GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)
```

resourceName is the name of the file with a full namespace. E.g. if your assembly default namespace (set in project settings) is "foo" and your file is in a folder called "bar" then resourceName would be something like "foo.bar.MyFile.xml"

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to do an XDocument.Load an pass in the name of your file.